# Change equation numbering without changing labels

Tags: equations, hyperref, numbering, cleveref, autoref

The crux of the issue is I want to refer to some equations as "Equation 1" in the body of the text. However, the actual numbering of the equations I want to appear as a right justified "eq. 1". Below is what I currently have.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%\def\theequation{eq. \arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
    Blah blah blah (\autoref{eq:nitrate_intro}). Also blah blah,
    \autoref{eq:reduce_intro}.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:nitrate_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{nitration_intro.png}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:reduce_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{reduction_intro.png}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

This is almost perfect. The only extra thing I need (for points) is to change the equation numbering from "(1)" to "(eq. 1)". I commented out this bit of code

```
\def\theequation{eq. \arabic{equation}}
```

The problem with that is that it makes the labels turn into "Equation eq. 1". Below is an example with the `\def\theequation` line uncommented.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! `\newtagform` from `mathtools` allows you to do that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{FG}{(eq.\ }{)}
\usetagform{FG}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%\def\theequation{eq. \arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
    Blah blah blah (\autoref{eq:nitrate_intro}). Also blah blah,
    \autoref{eq:reduce_intro}.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:nitrate_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{example-image-a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:reduce_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{example-image-b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to confine this effect to these equations, you can switch back to normal with `\usetagform{default}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{FG}{(eq.\ }{)}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%\def\theequation{eq. \arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
    Blah blah blah (\autoref{eq:nitrate_intro}). Also blah blah,
    \autoref{eq:reduce_intro}.\usetagform{FG}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:nitrate_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{example-image-a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:reduce_intro}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=c]{example-image-b}
\end{equation}
\usetagform{default}

\end{document}
```